# Permissions to edit network configuration

Tags: linux, security, permissions, virtual-machines

We ship a virtual machine to the clients which runs a web service. Clients need to install this virtual machine on one of their hosts using an hypervisor and just need to modify the network configuration to access the web service.

We do not want to give full root access to clients for modifying just the network configuration. We thought of adding a new user with sudo privileges on /etc folder but this may other consequences. What is the best of handling it?

P.S.: There is no USB access on the machines where the virtual machines are installed.

Comment: Create a user with UID=0 and GID=0 with `/usr/sbin/system-config-network-tui` or equivalent as the shell and direct your clients to configure the network from the console of their VM.

Comment: Often you'll see init spawning a menu on the console which allows network configuration, upgrading and debugging.

Comment: @HBruijn Our virtual machine is fully configured with IP configured while creating virtual machine and is stripped down version of Redhat . User does not see any options to configure network during startup. I do not see any network configuration scripts in /usr/sbin.

Comment: Why don't you want to give them root? It's a VM running on *their* host, they can trivially get root anyway if they really want to.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Since giving root privileges gives them unrestricted write access. Any misconfiguration can lead to nightmares for the support team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be very restrictive with sudo and tie a user down to a specific set of commands

It may be easier in the long run if you actually write a script that gathers the relevant information and modifies/generates files as required for the user and restarts networking. Then you will have a simpler sudo setup

```
user (ALL)=(root) /path/to/setup-script
```

Ensure that only root can edit the script. A side benefit of this is that you don't have to teach people how to use $EDITOR of choice and your files can be generated in a consistent manner.

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider the use of group memberships for this.  Create a group for the purpose

```
sudo groupadd netedit
```

Give the maintenance users secondary membership of that group in /etc/groups, with the tool of your choice, then delegate edit privileges on the file(s) you want:

```
sudo chgrp netedit /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
sudo chmod g+w /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```